# GitLab CI Build not uploading artifacts of codeception

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have problems with GitLab not uploading the artifacts generated by codeception when a test fails. It only uploads the `.gitignore` in the `_output` folder.
This is the relevant part from my `.gitlab-ci.yml`:

```
  - ./src/Vendor/codeception/codeception/codecept run acceptance || true
  - ls -a tests/_output
  artifacts:
    paths:
    - "tests/_output"
    expire_in: 20 days
    when: always
```

Interesting is, that I can browse the artifacts (in this case only the .gitignore-file) before the job even finished. The logs of my runner prove, that the artifacts do indeed exist in the directory `tests/_output` (shorted):

```
$ ls -a tests/_output
.
..
.gitignore
commentsCest.answerCommentTest.fail.html
commentsCest.answerCommentTest.fail.png
commentsCest.normalCommentTest.fail.html
commentsCest.normalCommentTest.fail.png
failed
Uploading artifacts...
tests/_output: found 2 matching files              
Uploading artifacts to coordinator... ok            id=123456789 responseStatus=201 Created token=abcdefghij
Job succeeded
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured out a workaround:

The gitlab-runner only uploads files properly inside the project directory. 
To get the artifacts, copy all files to `${CI_PROJECT_DIR}`:

```
codeception_tests:
  stage: <your stage-name>
  image: <your image>
  script:
  - ...
  after_script:
  - mkdir ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/artifacts
  - mkdir ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/artifacts/codecept
  - cp tests/_output ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/artifacts/codecept -R
  artifacts:
    paths:
      - ${CI_PROJECT_DIR}/artifacts/
    expire_in: 5 days
    when: always
```

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks. I was running Maven - pipeline through Gitlab.com.